# Run both functions simultaneaously not working (Google Sheets Script)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I've been trying to get these two functions together, so that the script runs as the user edits any of the sheets, but only the first function is running normally. The second one doesn't output anything, nor does this show any erros. I can't figure out where the flaw is here:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var watchedCols = [3, 4, 5]; //Se quiser adicionar mais colunas mudadas que estampam o horário na primeira coluna, adicione ", 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9" nos cochetes.
  var watchedSheet = 'To Do List'; //change name if needed
  if (watchedCols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) === -2 || ss.getName() !== watchedSheet || e.range.rowStart < 8) return;
  ss.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 2)
  .setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("DD/mm/yyyy")
  Logger.log(watchedCols)

  var watchedCols2 = [2, 3]; //Se quiser adicionar mais colunas mudadas que estampam o horário na primeira coluna, adicione ", 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9" nos cochetes.
  var watchedSheet2 = 'Updates'; //change name if needed
  if (watchedCols2.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) === -2 || ss.getName() !== watchedSheet2 || e.range.rowStart < 5) return;
  ss.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1)
  .setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("DD/mm/yyyy")
  Logger.log(watchedCols2)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the 2nd control structure return from the `onEdit()`

Comment: I tried it , but my limited knowledge certainly didn't allow for sucessful attempts. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only see one function, but I assume you are trying to merge two onEdits() into a single one? If so, replace the script you have with

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss, watchedSheets, startRows, watchedCols, stampCols, sheetInd;
ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
watchedSheets = ['To Do List', 'Updates'];
startRows = [8, 5];
watchedCols = [[3, 4, 5], [2, 3]]; 
stampCols = [2, 1];
sheetInd = watchedSheets.indexOf(ss.getName());
if(sheetInd === -1 || watchedCols[sheetInd].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) === -1 
|| e.range.rowStart < startRows[sheetInd]) return;
ss.getRange(e.range.rowStart, stampCols[sheetInd])
.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("DD/mm/yyyy");
}
```

and see if that works?